# How to dynamically create a similar multi-level JSON within this 2d loop?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am looping through a 2d array `["cat","dog","bird"]`

In that loop how would I dynamically construct a multi-level JSON that looks like this? The ideal answer would construct the json object and assign it to a variable. The expected format is shown below and you can assume that the words represent the iteration variable, or in the case of the oppositeName attribute it is a string concatenation "-" + iteration variable.

```
{"cat":
    {
    "name":"cat",
    "nickname":"cat",
    "oppositeName":"-cat"
    }
},
{"dog":
    {
    "name":"dog",
    "nickname":"dog",
    "oppositeName":"-dog"
    }
},
{"bird":
    {
    "name":"bird",
    "nickname":"bird",
    "oppositeName":"-bird"
    }
}
```

Comment: do you like to get an array or an object as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const final = {};

['cat', 'dog', 'bird'].forEach(creature => {
  final[creature] = {
    "name": creature,
    "nickname": creature,
    "oppositeName": `-${creature}`
  }
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map objects with the given name and their data.

For an array, you could use this.

```js
var array = ["cat","dog","bird"];
    result = array.map(a => ({
        [a]: {
            name: a,
            nickName: a,
            opositeName: '-' + a
        }
    }));
    
console.log(result);
```

For an object, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
var array = ["cat","dog","bird"];
    result = Object.assign(...array.map(a => ({
        [a]: {
            name: a,
            nickName: a,
            opositeName: '-' + a
        }
    })));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach:

```
let animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']
let result = animals.map(a => ({[a]: {name: a, nickname: a, oppositeName: '-' + a}}))
```